# Find string and make it bold in output E-mail

Tags: linux, command-line, scripting, output

i have below code which check status of some services on linux rhel 7 and send email (output is different service status). i want to make specific string called "up" and or  "NOT up" in bold and with blue color font. How can i do it ?

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /temp
./script1.sh status | mail -s "subject-line" myemail@com
```

Comment: Find the right colour codes for blue and bold, and then do something like: `| sed 's/up/<color_codes_here>up/g'`

Comment: I don't think this works for Email, probably needs some HTML, but `sed` should do.

Answer (score 0):

Add some HTML to your string using `sed`:

```
echo "Service is up" \
| sed 's/\<up\>/<span style="color: blue; font-weight:bold;">up<\/span>/'
```

Output:

```
Service is <span style="color: blue; font-weight:bold;">up</span>
```

Comment: i believe i don't have to use "echo" statement, isn't it? tried this without any error but not achieving goal                                                                                            **#!/bin/sh
cd /temp
./script1.sh status | sed 's/\<up\>/<span style="color: blue; font-weight:bold;">up<\/span>/' | mail -s "subject-line" myemail@com **

Comment: i am still sending command output directly to email